# how to remove whitespace and carriage return in xml using xstream

Tags: xstream

I am trying to linearize (remove whitespaces and carriage return) to compact XML.

Input is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<books> 
    <book> 
       <title>Basic XML</title> 
       <price>100</price> 
       <qty>5</qty> 
    </book> 
    <book> 
        <title>Basic Java</title> 
        <price>200</price> 
        <qty>15</qty> 
    </book> 
</books>
```

Output is as follows.

77u/PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiPz4gDQo8Ym9va3M+IA0KICAg
PGJvb2s+IA0KICAgICAgIDx0aXRsZT5CYXNpYyBYTUw8L3RpdGxlPiANCiAgICAgICA8cHJpY2U+
MTAwPC9wcmljZT4gDQogICAgICAgPHF0eT41PC9xdHk+IA0KICAgPC9ib29rPiANCiAgIDxib29r
PiANCiAgICAgPHRpdGxlPkJhc2ljIEphdmE8L3RpdGxlPiANCiAgICAgPHByaWNlPjIwMDwvcHJp
Y2U+IA0KICAgICA8cXR5PjE1PC9xdHk+IA0KICAgPC9ib29rPiANCjwvYm9va3M+

Code to convert is as follows.

public class XMLCompactTest {

```
public void testCompact() throws SAXException, IOException,
        ParserConfigurationException {

    final InputStream is =
            XMLCompactTest.class.getResourceAsStream("/example.xml");

    final byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
    final byte[] compactedBytes = compactXml(bytes);

    final String after = new String(compactedBytes);

    System.out.println(after);
}

 public static byte[] compactXml(final byte[] value)
        throws SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException {

    final ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    final XStream xs = new XStream();
    xs.autodetectAnnotations(true);
    xs.setMode(XStream.ID_REFERENCES);
    //xs.marshal(value, new CompactWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(bout, "UTF-8")));
    xs.marshal(value, new CompactWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(bout)));

    return bout.toByteArray();
}
```

}

Any help is very much appreciated, I have referred to other answers that deal with compacting xml and they do not seem to work for me. I am using xstream 1.4.3.

I am expecting a single line compacted and decoded xml.

Kind Regards.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing here is to marshal a byte array. Which of course gives some fancy results.

I would simply write the `compactXml()` method by hand.

```
public static String compactXml(final byte[] value) {
   String in = new String(value, "UTF-8");
   StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
   for(int i=0;i<in.length();i++) {
      char c = in.charAt(i);
      if(c != '\n' || c != ' ') {
         sb.append(c);
      }
   }
return sb.toString();
}
```